# pyodbc unpacking SQL_GUID for converting to lowercase string

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

sql-server and pyodbc return all SQL_GUID datatypes in uppercase, while queries are case-insensitive:

```
psql.py --sql="select controllerid from controllers where controllerid='F573A57D-9247-44CB-936A-D16DD4E8327F'"
[('F573A57D-9247-44CB-936A-D16DD4E8327F', )]
psql.py --sql="select controllerid from controllers where controllerid='f573a57d-9247-44cb-936a-d16dd4e8327f'"
[('F573A57D-9247-44CB-936A-D16DD4E8327F', )]
```

I want it to output in lowercase.
Added a pyodbc.add_output_converter() method which just does a lower on SQL_GUID but this is a packed structure:

```
def guid_to_lowercase(value):
    return value.lower()

pyodbc.add_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_GUID, guid_to_lowercase)

[(b'}\xa5s\xf5g\x92\xcbd\x93j\xd1m\xd4\xe82\x7f', )]
```

It looks like a byte, but changing it:

```
def guid_to_lowercase(value):
    #log.error("type:{}".format(type(value)))
    return value.decode("ascii").lower()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I assume I need to unpack it, but how is the format.

Outside of pyodbc I can do a uuid.lower()

Comment: pyodbc is already unpacking the value to a string, so why not just convert that string to lowercase and save yourself the trouble of unpacking it all over again?

Comment: Or, alternatively, `SELECT LOWER(controllerid) FROM controllers ...`

Comment: Hi @Gord I user "guid-string".lower() and lower(guidcollumn) today, but it talk to rest apis where all guids are lowercase, and there are more than 50 different guid collumns in the framework but there are also other identifiers macstring, serialstring etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we print out the raw bytes returned by the server for the GUID

```
'F573A57D-9247-44CB-936A-D16DD4E8327F'
```

we get

```
b'}\xa5s\xf5g\x92\xcbd\x93j\xd1m\xd4\xe82\x7f'
```

Converting the ASCII characters to their hex values, removing the `\x` prefixes, and adding some spaces we get

```
7da573f5 4792 cb44 936a d16dd4e8327f
```

revealing that SQL Server ODBC is returning the bytes for the GUID, but the first three segments are in little-endian order, while the last two segments are in big-endian order.

So, if we change our output converter function to

```python
def guid_to_lowercase(value):
    first_three_values = struct.unpack('<I2H', value[:8])
    fourth_value = struct.unpack('>H', value[8:10])[0]
    fifth_value = struct.unpack('>Q', b'\x00\x00' + value[10:16])[0]
    guid_string_parts = (
        '{:08x}'.format(first_three_values[0]),
        '{:04x}'.format(first_three_values[1]),
        '{:04x}'.format(first_three_values[2]),
        '{:04x}'.format(fourth_value),
        '{:012x}'.format(fifth_value),
    )
    return '-'.join(guid_string_parts)
```

it returns

```
'f573a57d-9247-44cb-936a-d16dd4e8327f'
```

Comment: Thanks @Gord as always You saved my day. Is there anywhere I can find the mssql-server raw datatypes described?.